# Rotate featured post image

Tags: featured-post

I am trying to have a s all box on my home page that will show the most recent 4 custom posts that are set with a featured tag. It is working and is showing the image of the most recent post and then just listing out the other 3 post titles under it which I want but I am tying to figure out a way to have the featured post that it is showing an image for change weekly to one of the other 4 posts so that they rotate.

Anyone have some suggestions of how I can do this?

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query('post_type=stories&story_tag=featured&posts_per_page=4' ); ?>
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php while( $recent->have_posts() ) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php if ($count < 2) : ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to    <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php  
if ( has_post_thumbnail()):  
the_post_thumbnail( 'feed-fixed' );  
endif;  ?></a>


      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent  Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
  <?php else : ?>
<ul>
<li>
      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent  Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

</li>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add time params to your WP_Query. Posts that have the same tag and were published during the current week:

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query('post_type=stories&story_tag=featured&posts_per_page=4&year='.date('Y').'&w='.date('W'); ?>
```

Source: [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) and me since i recently did this.